# Power Converter Control Platform for Commercial Use

Tags: power, converter, controller, industry

I'm designing a power converter for commercial use and I've been struggling to find a control platform that meets the typical industrial standards and can be used to do the control of the whole device.

The device should basically have several digital and analog inputs and outputs, along with communication capabilities and the capacity to execute control operations. The actual functions it should perform are the following:

- Protection (receive several digital and analog signals and enable/disable the converter depending on their values)
- Measurement & control (receive scaled-down analog signals and perform basic PI control)
- Synchronization with the grid using PLL
- Semiconductor triggering (send turn-on/-off signals to the drivers)
- Communicate with the customer's SCADA system so that the operation can be supervised remotely

So far I've found [this product from teknocea](https://www.teknocea.cat/components/control-board/CDA01CU3.html) for about USD 1300 based on TI's F28M36 MCU. I imagine there must be other options available. I'm not considering a PLC because they usually operate at low frequencies, but if you know products from this kind that can do the job, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: [What happens to shopping questions?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Buy a PLC or look at Wago products.

Comment: @Andyaka Why do you say the question is off-topic and then provide an answer? "No, you can't have any candy but here is a lollypop." You just provide an incentive for more shopping questions.

Comment: PAC vs PLC vs PCI cards in a PC . Shop for PCI IO cards and software, by modules or systems. But Wuawei make the best, yet perhaps only integrated to their GTI. Although one major utilized had issues blowing rated fuses when wind power converter neighbours came only line due to noisy disturbances so  they just used 200A fuses instead of 150A